# How to set condition for function call on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular6, angular7

I have a table which consists of columns named **NoBill** and **Bill** which has checkbox as values.

Table default view

[image]

When **NoBill** checkbox gets clicked once **totale**(**this.totale**) value gets calculated.

Totale value at top after two checkbox clicked in nobill column

[image]

When  **Bill** column  checkbox gets clicked once **total**(**this.total**) value gets calculated. It also opens two new columns named **Ratio** and **Revasst**.

Total value at top and ratio calculation here

[image]

The formula for getting value for **Ratio** is (**total**/**totale**). For example if **total** is 110 and if **totale** is 100 then the ratio is 110/100=1.1.

So when I click the same **Bill** column  checkbox repeatedly (2 times to enable and disable)
the value **total**(**this.total**) gets repeatedly calculated. So now the **total** value gets updated from 110 to 120. So because of that the **Ratio** value gets changed to 1.2 as now its 120/100 instead of 110/100. This is the issue I am facing. I just want the **total** value to be calculated only once for a single checkbox click. So that it stays 110 for that checkbox click even though its clicked multiple times.

Ratio value change after clicking same checkbox value repeatedly

[image]

[My stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qwwntr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you has severals variables, this make difficult to check.

Imagine you has a function like

```
  calculateTotals()
  {
    const items=this.listes.filter(x=>x.nobillChecked || x.billChecked)
    const total=items.length?items.map(x=>x.qty*x.value).reduce((totals, data) => totals + data):0

    const items2=this.listes.find(x=>x.billChecked)?this.listes.filter(x=>x.nobillChecked):[]
    const totale=items2.length?items2.map(x=>x.qty*x.value).reduce((totals, data) => totals + data):0
    const factor=totale && total?total/totale:0
    return [total,totale,factor]
  }
```

See that this function only depend from the values of "listes" and don't change any value

you can use in your .html some like

```
            <tr *ngFor="let list of listes; index as i">
                <td>{{list.name}}</td>
                <td>{{list.qty}}</td>
                <td>{{list.value}}</td>
                <ng-container *ngIf="factor">
                    <td>
                        <div *ngIf="list.nobillChecked;">{{ factor|number:'1.0-2' }}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div *ngIf="list.nobillChecked;">{{list.value*factor|number:'1.0-2' }}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            {{list.nobillChecked?(list.qty*factor*list.value|number:'1.0-2'):''}}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
                <td *ngIf="!factor">
                    <div>
                        {{list.nobillChecked?(list.qty*list.value|number:'1.0-2'):''}}
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Bikee"
      [disabled]="list.billChecked"
      [(ngModel)]="list.nobillChecked"
      (change)="recalculate()"
    >
  </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Bikes"
      [disabled]="list.nobillChecked"
      [(ngModel)]="list.billChecked"
      (change)="recalculate()"
    >
  </td>
            </tr>
```

Again, take account the values only depending form "list", "factor", "total" and "totale". You can, in (change) simply calculate again the values

```
  recalculate() {
    [this.totale,this.total,this.factor]=this.calculateTotals()
  }
```

(I use the "destructuring" to give value to the three variables). Well, the function return an array, with destructuring give value to the variables.

I don't prety sure make it correcttly [in the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bjul9q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), but think that less variables and less variables to acumulate, makes the things more easy to check. And yes, can look that "recalculate" all is not very good when we thnking in performance. Really the time to spend in "recalculate" all it's not significance, and make the code more "robust"

Comment: The only is calculate the qut*value, first filter is "nobillChecked" and "billChecked", and teh calculate the sum (we need take account when the array if empty). I prefer return an array with the values of the functions and use destructuring: Destructuring it's only that in typescript you can write some like `[this.a,this.b]=[1,2]` is equal to make `this.a=1;this.b=2`. Anohter way is simply in the function make `this.total=total;this.totale=total;this.factor=factor`, and don't return anything, simply call to the function.

Comment: if items.length (if the array contains it's not an a empty array), make the map and reduce, else the value is 0, it's the "ternary operator": `value=(condition)?value1:value2`it's the same that `if (condition)value=value1 else value=value2`

Comment: I make factor= total/totale only if totale<>0 and total<>0 (both), else factor=0 -it's to make easy how show the values in .html- Yes, in typescript you can use `if (variable){...}` it's the same that `ìf (variable!==0 && variable!==undefined && variable!==null && avariable!==""){...}`

Comment: <>0 -can be negative-

Comment: `*ngIf="factor"` show if factor<>0 `*ngIf="!factor"` show only if factor==0

Comment: Hey I am facing a big problem. I implemented the stackblitz code in my real code. When the checkbox click happens in nobill column all the checkboxes gets disabled in the bill column. The only difference is that in stackblitz its a hardcoded list and here I get it from service?  @Eliseo

Comment: Leno, the problem is not here -I just updated the stackblitz to use a service -well really I "simulate the call to the api using of and delay-. See if you see an error in console or if you're put corecttly the variable. BTW In stackblitz I use a "map" to transfrom the data from service to add the two properties "billChecked" and "nobillChecked"

Comment: I have tried this way at my code but the whole tablle data is now not showing @Eliseo

Comment: leno check the data you are receiving

Comment: result.forEach is not a function  is the error I am getting @Eliseo

Comment: try your result.data.forEach and equal this.listes=result.data. I try to explain. you received some data, this data can be directly and array,e.g. `[{,,,,},{...}]` or an object `data:[{...},{...}]` or another thing -this is the reason to, in subscribe write `console.log(result)` to see in console -with F12- waht are you receiving. We only want the "array", so we need know where the array is

Comment: can u come on chat?

Comment: It is the second type an object. I am writing all these outside onit in my vs code @Eliseo

Comment: Now the data has come on screen. But the issue remains same. all checkboxes getting disabled instead of one